# Where are Windows 10 Mail "verbose diagnostic logs" stored?

Tags: windows, email, email-client

I enabled Diagnostic logging in the Windows 10 Mail app, but I don't know where to find these logs:

[image]

Through logs I'm trying to find out why my emails get stuck in the outbox and are not sent. This only happens for one particular email account and the issue goes away after I restart the system. So I know it's not because of misconfiguration or incorrect password.

I know this [question has been asked before](https://superuser.com/questions/1549812/where-is-the-log-of-windows-10-mail-app), but there are no answers. Thank you!

Comment: More than likely in the users Temp folder

Answer (score 0):

I found it. After enabling the verbose diagnostic logging, an ETL file (HxmLog.etl) can be found in this directory:

```
%localappdata%\Packages\microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\
```

You have to open that file in Event Viewer to see the logs.

I found this by using the Resource Monitor to see which files were opened by the process.